# This works for one cell - now how can I apply it to a range?

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following formula which works perfectly fine with one cell reference.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(SPLIT($B$20," "),C7)))=COUNTA(SPLIT($B$20," "))
```

The problem is I just cannot work out how to make this work for a cell range. The truth is more than likely that I've simply exceeded the limits of my abilities with GSheets, but here it is...

Cell B20 contains a phrase of two or more words. How can I search Cells C3:C12 and return a count of how many cells contain all the words? (Note: not as a phrase match, that I can do, it needs to be all the words from the phrase but in no particular order).

Would be grateful for any insights. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try

```
=SUM(ArrayFormula(--(MMULT(--iferror(regexmatch(split(C3:C12; " "); substitute(B20; " ";"|"))); TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("1_"; MAX(LEN(C3:C12)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C3:C12; " ";))+1)); "_")))>=COUNTA(SPLIT(B20; " ")))))
```

To make the match case-insensitive, try:

```
=SUM(ArrayFormula(--(MMULT(--iferror(regexmatch(split(C3:C12; " "); "(?i)"&substitute(B20; " ";"|"))); TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("1_"; MAX(LEN(C3:C12)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C3:C12; " ";))+1)); "_")))>=COUNTA(SPLIT(B20; " ")))))
```

Note: Depending on your locale, you may have to change the semi colons to commas.

Comment: This is genius, thank you so much. I've literally spent days trying to work this out. Someone suggested MMULT might be necessary but, after looking into that, honestly I had no idea how to proceed! Would it be difficult to make this case-insensitive? I just tried but messed it up :)

Comment: Hi, @ChrisGreenhough. To make the match case-insensitive add "(?i)"& just before substitute(B20; " ";"|") and see if that works? Also see updated answer.

Comment: Holy moly! That's it. I can't thank you enough. That seems like voodoo to me!

Comment: Excuse my lack of familiarity, new to Stack Overflow so really don't yet know the protocol. I have a related issue with a formula (on the same sheet) and could really use your help. Should I open that as a new question?

Comment: Yes, start a new topic and we'll see what we can do to help.

Comment: Posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53562460/10723594. If you have time to take a look, that would be fantastic :)