# How to convert conditional formatting formula to cell-based formula for cell range?

Tags: google-sheets

Here's my next challenge, and it's related to the previous one (found here: [This works for one cell - now how can I apply it to a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53543287/10723594)).

I've ended up with a godawful ugly formula for conditional formatting, and somehow (perhaps by dumb luck) it seems to work...

```
=OR(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$18,D7)),SIGN(SEARCH($B$18,D7)),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(SPLIT($B$19,","),D7)),SEARCH(SPLIT($B$19,","),D7)))))
```

It returns true for any single target cell (D7 in this example), checking whether it contains either the string in B18 or one of two or more string values, separated by commas, in B19.

As with the previous scenario, I can't work out how to turn this into a formula (array formula?) which I can apply to a range (D3:D12) and count how many cells meet the criteria.

Or maybe the better question is, what would be the correct way to tackle this in preference to my Frankenstein's Monster of a kludged-up formula quoted above!

Any and all insights appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the values in B19 are separated by a comma, followed by a space, try:

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(--(REGEXMATCH(D3:D12, B18&"|"&SUBSTITUTE(B19, ", ", "|")))))
```

If there is no space after the comma use "," instead of ", ".
If you want the match to be case-insensitive, try:

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(--(REGEXMATCH(D3:D12, "(?i)"&B18&"|"&SUBSTITUTE(B19, ", ", "|")))))
```

See if that works?

Comment: Thanks @JPV. This seems to return only the cells containing the string from B18. I got the same result when I tried this:

`=filter( D3:D12, iferror( search($B$18, D3:D12) ) + iferror( search( transpose(split($B$19,","), D3:D12))))`

But I realise my own code is prone to errors that are likely obvious to anyone else :)

Comment: Correction, I neglected to remove the space after the comma. This works perfectly :) Many thanks, once again.